# parse a text file and remove the special characters in set of lines

Tags: linux, csv, parsing

I have below csv file with below contents. This is just a snapshot

```
"[2015] Google Nexus Project"
"2.4GHz Antenna"
"AC Study Dev 2GHz MMIC blocks"
2ndlineTAM
"8D GaN Rth fails after temp stress tests"
90NV Dual Source
"TFA9890R RDL ASEK"
"93k platform introduction BU ID"
```

Like above i have around 2000+ lines, what i require is to remove the double quotes and the output should be like below:

```
[2015] Google Nexus Project
2.4GHz Antenna
AC Study Dev 2GHz MMIC blocks
2ndlineTAM
8D GaN Rth fails after temp stress tests
90NV Dual Source
TFA9890R RDL ASEK
93k platform introduction BU ID
```

Could any one please suggest how to parse and remove the double quotes, but it should only remove double quotes and no other special character should be removed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did (or didn't) your attempt work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have tried using sed and parse the while, but i am not sure how to make it for each line

Comment: How about using the `sed` command `s` to replace leading and trailing double-quotes with nothing? Like e.g. `'s/^"//'` for leading quotes?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have tried it, but the problem is in few of the lines it would remove the first quote but not the last one in the line. like "abc" , it removes abc"

Comment: Chain the pipe into a `sed` command that removes the trailing quote? Or try to come up with a regex that can remove both? Go to http://regex101.com/ and experiment!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks , this helps a lot for me to learn too. I was not aware of this. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply we can use this - `sed -e 's/[""]//g' file.csv`

Comment: It is useless to put the same character twice into a character range. And it is useless to use a character range at all for a single character. And it is less efficient to use a regular expression replacement instead of a simple string replacement. `sed -e 's/"//g'` is about 20 times slower than `tr -d \"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr -d` to delete characters.

```
$ echo '"a"' | tr -d \"
a
```